# Find usages of inherited method only from a specific subclass?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I have a superclass which is inherited by many subclasses. I would like to find all calls to a certain method in this superclass which originate from instances of a specific inheriting class.  Is this possible in VS2012 (with Resharper 7.1)?

*Code example:*

```
public class Super
{
    public void foo(Arg a)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Sub1 : Super
{
    ...
}

public class Sub2 : Super
{
    ...
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public void Run()
    {
        ...
        var sub1 = new Sub1();
        sub1.foo(a);

        var sub2 = new Sub2();
        sub2.foo(b);
    }
}
```

I would like to find only the call `sub2.foo(b)` not `sub1.foo(a)` in the example above.

Comment: I would assume resharper is able to do this. However i don't have it installed right now, so i can only suggest the workaround to temporarily generate a method stub with the same overloads in Sub2 and use the "find all references" functionality in VS.

Comment: I can't find a way to do it, but I would think it's possible. Thanks for the tip of creating an override. It will work, but I'd like to avoid modifying the code if possible.

Comment: @Polymorphix did you manage to find an answer for this? I'm still searching...

Comment: @NotAPro, No, I did not find an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use Structural Search and Replace to set up a pattern to find the usages. Go to ReSharper -> Find -> Search with Pattern. Create a pattern such as `$exp$.Foo($args$)`. Then add an "expression" placeholder for `exp`. You can specify what type this should be, and check the tick box to specify exact type. Here you'd enter the fully qualified type `All.Your.Namespaces.Sub2`. Then add an "arguments" placeholder for `args`. Leave everything unchecked - it will match any number of arguments. Clicking find should find all calls to `Foo` from any expression that matches `Sub2`.

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work. The only search expression I've managed to get working when specifying a type for `$exp$` is when `$exp$` is a static class, i.e. it doesn't match instances of the class.