# Find usages for methods resolved to a certain type in Resharper and/or Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I am wondering if there exists a feature that allows Resharper to only look for methods on a given, concrete type instead of all the occurences of this method in any given type in the inheritance hierarchy of the class where the method is originally defined. Let me give an example to clarify. Let's say I have the following hierarchy

```
    public class A
    {
        public void Foo() { }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
    }
```

And somewhere in my code, I have this logic

```
        A myAClass = new A();
        myAClass.Foo();

        B myBClass = new B();
        myBClass.Foo();
```

Looking for usages of `Foo()` will yield 2 results, since the method itself is used at `myAClass.Foo()` and `myBClass.Foo()`, but is there a way to look for the `Foo()` method being used on a given type (in this instance class `B` ) and not in any other type on which this method is accessible anywhere else in the hierarchy, both up and down ?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521657/find-usages-of-inherited-method-only-from-a-specific-subclass

Answer (score 0):

Invoke ReSharper's "Advanced Find Usages" command (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> for VS shortcut scheme, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> for IntelliJ scheme). This allows you to choose between the derived or declaring instance (e.g. `Base.Foo` or `Derived.Foo`). You can now choose to find usages of just the symbol defined in the derived class.

Comment: This doesn't work if A and B are interfaces.  Only A.Foo is offered to search for, not B.Foo.